# SQL Server dependencies in Spring Boot Gradle Java application

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to connect a database to my Spring Boot application using Gradle.
On the internet I only find examples for Maven projects, using the pom.xml file.
I don't know for sure, but I think build.gradle is the equivalent in Gradle? What should I add to it to add support for Microsoft SQL Server?

This is my build.gradle right now:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group = 'Project'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

application{
    mainClassName 'project.rlstop.Publisher'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.bundles', name: 'jaxrs-ri', version: '2.+'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet', version: '2.+'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.+'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.+'



    // Grizzly will host the service
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-grizzly2-http', version: '2.+'


    // Logging
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '2.+'
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '2.+'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know for sure, but I think build.gradle is the equivalent in Gradle?

Yes, it is. `build.gradle` is to Gradle what `pom.xml` is to Maven.

> What should I add to it to add support for Microsoft SQL Server?

You currently have a dependency to the MySQL JDBC driver declared:

```
runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
```

To use MS SQL Server, you need to replace that with

```
runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
```

You may explorer a skeleton project using the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.3.4.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=sqlserver,web,data-jpa). You may also refer to the [Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) for instructions on how to configure the data source properties to connect to your MS SQL Server.